# TCPClient.Close() doesn't work when using Mono

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, tcpclient, disconnect

I'm trying to simply disconnect socket client.

```
TcpClient socket = new TcpClient();
NetworkStream stream = socket.GetStream();
// ...
stream.Close();
socket.Close();
```

Well, it works perfectly fine(server notices when client disconnects) when launching it *without* Mono on Windows. When using Mono on Windows or Linux it just doesn't work, server doesn't notice that client disconnected. What should be a proper solution for this? And **why** does this happens?

Comment: try with Dispose? (if it works with Dispose, it's anyway a mono bug, which you should file in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ )

Comment: still doesn't work with Dispose, submited it to bugzilla.

Comment: post the URL of the bug here

Comment: here it is: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12012